# To Increase Performance of Barcode scanning

Tags: sql, .net, windows, c#-4.0

Iam Working on POS Application it is an windows application.

we have barcode lengths starting from 5 to 16. here iam using textbox change event for getting scanned barcode, so after scanning barcode i need to check details on server based on barcode. here the problem is textbox event when i scanned item that event is called for each digit. upto 5 is ok but after that i need to check 6 to 16 characters one by one. due to this barcode scanning performance is reduced.

Answer (score 0):

You've given very litle information however assuming you are using a barcode scanner in HID mode (simulating keyboard rather than directly connected to a serial port) and assuming you are using the TextChanged event then yes the event will fire each time a charachter is appended to the TextBox.

What you therefore need to do is to introduce a timer to introduce a delay (e.g. 200ms) before checking the barcode, if the event fires again before the timer has elapsed then reset the timer, otherwise when the timer fires check the barcode.

```
private System.Timers.Timer barcodeTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(200);
private void barcodeTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    barcodeTimer.Stop();
    barcodeTimer.Start();
}

private void barcodeTimer_Elapsed(object sender, Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    barcodeTimer.Stop();
    processBarcode();
}
```

(Converted from VB.Net so apologies for errors)

Comment: 200ms after there have been no more changes to the TextBox.Text